# What is the best way to recreate the Google Spaces navbar in a React Native app?

Tags: react-native

The Google Spaces app had a raised bump in its bottom navigation. I kinda liked the look but I'm not sure how best to recreate it using React Native.

I'm assuming it would be something like adding an image above the navbar to show the bump but that doesn't seem right since the  actual button in the navbar wouldn't extend into the curved area.

Here's a link to an image of the navbar in question:

[image: Figure 1]